# How to put label item on rowLayout in SWT?

Tags: eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp

I want to put some items on row layout. But I take an error. My error image is here:

[image]

my example code is below:

```
GridLayout parentLayout = new GridLayout(1, true);
    parent.setLayout(parentLayout);

    // design filter composite layout
    Composite filterComposite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);

    RowLayout filterCompositeLayout = new RowLayout();
    filterCompositeLayout.wrap = true;
    filterCompositeLayout.pack = false;
    filterCompositeLayout.justify = true;
    filterCompositeLayout.type = SWT.HORIZONTAL;
    filterComposite.setLayout(filterCompositeLayout);

    // design filter composite
    Label lbl_type = new Label(filterComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    lbl_type.setText("Type :");

Combo cmb_type = new Combo(filterComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    cmb_type.setText("-- choose --");

    Label lbl_severity = new Label(filterComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    lbl_severity.setText("Severity :");

    Combo cmb_severity = new Combo(filterComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    cmb_severity.setText("-- choose --");

    Label lbl_startDate = new Label(filterComposite, SWT.BORDER);
    lbl_startDate.setText("Start Date : ");

    DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(filterComposite, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
    dateTimeStart.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.NONE, SWT.NONE, true, true));
```

Error is on DataTime row. Can anybody give some advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant set GridData to component placed in RowLayout. You should use RowData instead:

```
    DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(filterComposite, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
    RowData rd = new RowData();
    rd.width = 123;
    rd.height = 23;
    dateTimeStart.setLayoutData(rd);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to set GridData layout data for dateTimeStart. However Composite filterComposite has RowLayout and this Layout expects RowData layout data.

example:

```
DateTime dateTimeStart = new DateTime(filterComposite, SWT.DROP_DOWN | SWT.LONG);
dateTimeStart.setLayoutData(new RowData (width, height)); //set proper height and width according to your UI expectations
```